# How does Flink handle windows and partitions that don't fit in memory?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

After having read a bit on [how Flink manages memory](https://flink.apache.org/news/2015/05/11/Juggling-with-Bits-and-Bytes.html) it still isn't obvious whether the input that is passed to `DataSet#mapPartitions` or `KeyedWindowedStream#process` is a lazy collection or not.

Having debugged a little bit for the window scenario it seems the answer is now given that the input is read from a `ListState` which maps to an `ArrayList` but was wondering if this is always the case (or if it depends on the size of the input).

Answer (score 1):

Batch and stream processing operator handle state very differently in Flink. The linked blog post explains how Flink's batch processing operators (which execute DataSet programs) manages memory. The stream processing operators (used by DataStream programs) use a pluggable state backend to store state.

The batch operators use algorithms which get a fixed memory budget and spill to disk if the data exceeds the budget. Examples are the external merge-sort or the hybrid hash join algorithms.

In stream processing applications, a pluggable state backend is responsible for maintaining, checkpointing, and restoring state. There are state backends which store state on the JVM heap. These will fail if the data in one process exceeds the available heap memory. However, there is also a `RocksDBStateBackend` which stores state in an embedded RocksDB instance on disk.

Comment: Ok I understand that but what happens if I'm using a filesystem state backend and `WindowedStream#process` gets called with contents that exceed the heap size? Considering that the `Iterable` is not lazy (which apparently isn't given that the window is using a list state that deserializes to `ArrayList`) the result will be out of memory exception, right?

Comment: Despite its name, the FSStateBackend holds state on the JVM heap. It only checkpoints all state to a remote file system. A job with FSStateBackend would fail as soon as the overall state of all operators in a TM process exceeds the JVM heap. 

Only the RocksDBStateBackend stores state on local disk. But also the RocksDBStateBackend will fail if the size of a single window exceeds the heap, just as you described.